# Significance of URL encode in AJAX POST

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I was trying to submit a form using ajax post and server was giving me 403 error(working fine with get). Later when I encoded my 'URL', it worked fine.
 What I can not understand is if I use method post then form data is going in the body of http packet. Then, what difference it makes if I encode my URL ? Why server is treating un-encoded URL acccess by POST as injection ?

```
  var uri = encodeURI($('#registrationForm').attr('action'));
            // 403 error if i do not use encodeURI, everything else same
              console.log(dataString);
                      $.ajax({

                      type:"POST",
                      url:uri,
                      data:dataString,
                      success:function(result){

                        console.log(result);

                        },

                      error:function(error){

                             alert(error);
                           }
                 });
```

Comment: What do you mean by *encoded my 'URL'* exactly? Can you provide actual code of what you did? A 403 HTTP response code generally means that the server refuses to grant you access to the request resource for one reason another. Why, remains entirely unclear here.

Comment: @Sherif Included the code.

Comment: Look at the value of `($('#registrationForm').attr('action')`, what is it? If you get an error without encoding it properly then clearly it's because the server doesn't accept a URI that isn't properly encoded. FYI, HTTP does require valid URL encoding of a request path.

Comment: So what I am getting is(correct me if I am wrong), server is checking for url encoding only for post method and assuming that get method will not be used for any state change on server(just for pulling pages) and so, url encoding is not checked. So, difference lies in the server configuration and not in http protocol for get and post.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know that. Which is why I was suggesting you examine the value of `$('#registrationForm').attr('action')` in both cases. For all I know they are different values between your `POST` request and your `GET` request. I'm not about to make any arbitrary assumptions without further debugging.

Answer (score 1):

What php framework(MVC) if you are using framework? and another what HTTP server (apache or nginx) as 403 Forbidden HTTP status code, and 403 is something to do with permission you dont have a permission to access the pages.

Instead of

```
 $.ajax({type:"POST",url:uri,data:{ ...
```

try change to

```
 $.ajax({type:"PUT",url:uri,data:{ ..
```

Comment: That I understand, but then it should not even work with get request. What difference does encoding the  url makes with permission check ?

Comment: it might be an issue related to apache mod_security.

Comment: Or your server .htaccess

Comment: I already got it working using encodeURI, so it is not about trying put. I just wanted to know the difference in behavior and effect of URL encoding in case of get and post.  Can u please elaborate a bit why should I use put ?  As both put and post can be used for creation, I am using post.